# proxy.conf.json problem localhost php backend

Tags: php, angular, localhost, port

Im working with Angular frontend and PHP backend.

Angular app running at: 8100
PHP api: localhost:80

This is my proxy.conf.json:

```
{
    "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

And in the package.json:

```
 "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

But when i try to send POST data to my PHP api i receive:

> POST http://localhost:**8100**/xxx/api/register

But my api is not running on 8100.

How can i change the port?

Thxs for your time.

I tried to obtain data from my PHP api on localhost

[image]

OUTPUT:
[image: output confusion api url]

Comment: I don't understand the problem here. The **whole point** of running a proxy on port 8100 is that the browser makes the HTTP request to the proxy instead of to the service being proxied. You seem to be complaining that you are using a proxy when you choose to use a proxy.

Comment: If i don't use the proxy i have problems with CORS. im new on this.

Comment: Well, yes, that's a common reason to use a proxy. I still don't understand the problem.

Comment: to fix problem CORS i use proxy.conf.json, but when i call the api on my localhost, is looking on port 8100, but my api is not working on that port. I must have some confusion about the functioning of the proxy, I will continue investigating. Thanks for your time

Comment: Thats what the proxy is doing. Browser sends a request to localhost:8100 then proxy kicks in and forwards the request to localhost:80.... you don't see that in the Browser (to avoid CORS) .. but you should see a log statement in your terminal

Comment: @ArianDiDonato — Is it really not working (i.e. you get a Network Timeout) or is it working but you're surprised that the proxy has port it listens on as well as a port it makes requests to?

Comment: Typo. Your proxy is forwarding requests which start with `/api/` and your request doesn't.

Comment: Until yesterday I was surprised by what I saw on the console, but I'm beginning to understand how it works, sorry for my confusion. I still have the problem and attach IMG.
127.0.0.1/mse-clean/api is where i have my backend files.